# For what kinds of manifolds $\dim T_pM=\dim M$ holds?

Tags: differential-geometry, manifolds

Does the truth that $\dim T_pM=\dim M$ hold only for differentiable manifolds or for all topological ones?

Comment: If the manifold isn't differentiable, how do you define $T_pM$?

Comment: It depends on the manifold under consideration and how you consider it. If you admit singularities at $p$, then the tangent space is not even well-defined...